# FirebaseError not resolved

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm writing an app that updates to Firebase but I can't write the oncancelled function because it `cannot resolve symbol FirebaseError`.

My code below:

```
package com.test.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import static com.test.myapplication.R.id.radioButton5;
import static com.test.myapplication.R.id.radioButton6;
import static com.test.myapplication.R.id.radioButton8;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;

public class OfficialDetail extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView textViewStreet;
TextView textViewLat;
TextView textViewLong;
TextView textViewDescription;
TextView textViewSeverity;
TextView textViewSize;
TextView textViewEmail;
RadioButton RadioButton5;
RadioButton RadioButton6;
RadioButton RadioButton8;
DatabaseReference mRef;
DatabaseReference dRef;

ArrayList<Report> reportArrayList;

Report value;
ListView mListView;


ImageView imgView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_item_detail);
    RadioButton5 = (RadioButton)findViewById(radioButton5);
    RadioButton6 = (RadioButton)findViewById(radioButton6);
    RadioButton8 = (RadioButton)findViewById(radioButton8);
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    initialize();


    if(intent!=null) {

        textViewStreet.setText(intent.getStringExtra("street_of"));
        textViewLat.setText(intent.getStringExtra("lat_of"));
        textViewLong.setText(intent.getStringExtra("long_of"));
        textViewDescription.setText(intent.getStringExtra("descrip_of"));
        textViewSeverity.setText(intent.getStringExtra("severity_of"));
        textViewSize.setText(intent.getStringExtra("size_of"));

        if(intent.getStringExtra("Off").equals("Official")){
            RadioButton5.setEnabled(false);
            RadioButton8.setEnabled(false);
        }else{
            RadioButton5.setEnabled(false);
            RadioButton6.setEnabled(false);
        }
        if (RadioButton6.isChecked()){
            reportArrayList = new ArrayList<>();


            dRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            mRef = dRef.child("report");
            Query qRef;
            qRef = dRef.orderByChild("Status").equalTo("still_there");

            qRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot tasksSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot: tasksSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        snapshot.getRef().child("Status").setValue("removal_confirmed");
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(**FirebaseError**  firebaseError) {
                    System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
                }
            });
        }
        byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(intent.getStringExtra("img_of"), Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
        imgView.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);


    }

}

private void initialize(){


    textViewStreet = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView22);
    imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    textViewDescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.item_detail);
    textViewSeverity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView24);
    textViewSize = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView26);
    textViewLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView13);
    textViewLong = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView17);

}
}
```

Is there an `import` statement I'm missing? How can I resolve this?

Comment: clean and rebuild the project

Comment: Hey, thanks  for the help but it didnt work..

Comment: I found how to solve the error. I had to change FirebaseError to DatabaseError. It seems FirebaseError is deprecated.

Comment: have a happy Coding

Comment: @Nima: you're mixing method signatures from two different SDK versions and that won't work. Given the rest of your code, the signature of `onCancelled` is: `public void onCancelled(DatabaseError  error)`

Comment: Weird they would depreciate 'FirebaseError' to the more generic 'DatabaseError', I was wondering why android studio didn't suggest the usual 'press alt+enter' shortcut to import the support code. 'FirebaseError' is still used in the current doc examples like here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-reading-once.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the `FirebaseError` class with `DatabaseError` class.

I had the same issue and what I did was just removed all the method codes and allowed the Android Studio to create the method definition itself. Then the `FirebaseError` was replaced with `DatabaseError` automatically.